# EXC_BAD_ACCESS disappears with zombies enabled

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, exc-bad-access

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash at startup and Xcode says the crash is at the `NSApplicationMain` line in my main.m file. The crash happens 99% of the time and when I run it with zombies enabled the crash never happens. Has anyone seen this before? How can I possibly debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Xcode4 there default is to show very little of the call stack, move the slider at the bottom to the right.  You may well not find any of your code but you should be able to get a good idea of what was going on.  If it was a notification or selector after delay you will see that the Runloop dispatch and that will also give you a clue.

Finally, go old school, the way we did it in the day of coding forums, punch cards and only a couple of compiles a day: study your code.  Know what every line of code does and why it is there.

As @Danra said, do run the Xcode Analyzer and fix all complaints.

Comment: tried moving the slider over, but that didn't really give me any clues. However, I enabled garbage collection and the crash went away. This works, but It does kind of bother me that the problem is still technically unresolved.

Comment: Actually, GC does solve the problem because all retain/release/autorelease are no-op'ed.

Comment: Turns out I'm not going to use GC, so I'd like to resolve this issue. Here's the log from the crash: http://pastie.org/2623237

Comment: You did not crash in main, that is just the way it looks because of the run loop, notice __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__, the runloop called the following code and there was a crash so there is no traceback to your code.  But it crashed in Core Location so that is a good hint.  the Put a breakpoint in the first statement of `ApplicationDidFinishLaunching`.  Try stepping through the code.  Last resort, go old school, really understand exactly what your code is doing.  Use the Feynman technique: fix the bug by thinking.

Comment: Any idea what exactly I'd be looking for? Is it something inside a CoreLocation delegate method? Am I accessing a deallocated object somewhere? Or is it pretty much ambiguous as to what causes the crash?

Comment: OK found the problem. I have a class that manages a CLLocationManager instance and for some reason CoreLocation didn't like how I was handling it. If I could explain it better I would haha. But I don't know exactly what I did that fixed it or what the problem really was. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why running with zombies enabled resolves the bad access is probably that a) In this mode objects don't really get deallocated when their retain count reaches zero, and b) That your original crash is due to accessing an already deallocated object.

However with zombies enabled, instead of the crash I think you should see in the debug console the access to the deallocated object.

I also recommend using the static analyzer ("Analyze" in the XCode menus) in hope that it finds the culprit.